# Help Window - WPF

Tags: wpf

I need to create some help window to my WPF application, is there any support for help 
content display\Build under WPF ??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about .chm help files?

Comment: I answered this here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12186075/515129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could like jskiles1 says make .chm files.

Take a look at [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/18/10118158/how-to-create-a-chm-help-file-for-wpf-application.aspx) page, you might find something you need other then .chm.
To create .chm though, there are plenty of tutorials on the net.