# CHM help on network share won't open from application

Tags: winforms, chm, html-help

I have a .NET WinForms application that uses CHM help file. Both executable and CHM are on a network share. I used http://www.helpandmanual.com/products_hhreg.html to create registry entries that could allow display of the help contents. If I open the file itself from the share all is OK. However, when I press F1 in my application to invoke help, I get the familiar "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" error. No matter what I do, including setting zone security level = 2 will help.
How do I go about using CHM help in my application when launched from a network share?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

I found this other approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/928156/1757491 which seems to allow me to view the help but when I use

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null, path);
```

I get what you describe.

Comment: Thanks, but we moved to HTML format help some years ago and there's no such problem.